# Why does tab completion not work for all rpm command options?

Tags: bash, rpm, autocomplete

When running the command `rpm --query --all` the options such as `--query` and `-all` are auto-completed when using the `tab` key.

When running the command `rpm --verify --all`, the option `--all` does not auto-complete nor does it appear as an option when depressing the `tab` key multiple times.

To execute the command `rpm --verify --all`, it has to entered in its entirety.

The bash shell is in use.

Why does the option `--all` for example not auto-complete or appear in the list of available options?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - The question has been updated.

Comment: The completion function probably doesn't have `--all` in its list of options.

Comment: @Olorin - Can you elaborate further? What do you men by the completion function doens't have `--all` in its list of options? It would seem odd since `--all` is available when using the command `rpm --query --all`.

Comment: It maybe checking the first option and looking up further applicable options, and `--all` is not in the list of applicable options for `--verify`.

Comment: @Olorin - Do you mean to say that subsequent flags/options are dependent on the first flag/option as opposed to the primary command for the purposes of auto-completion? If yes, that would require knowing the command and its library of flags/options in some depth?

Comment: It could be. It all depends on what the completion function contains. Some functions are simple and complete options regardless of position, some are complex.

Comment: @Olorin - Is the lack of  a response in auto-completing sufficient to indicate that it's not supported? I have observed that the sequence of the options/flags influences the choice of subsequent options/flags.

Comment: Supported by what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88940/discussion-between-motivated-and-olorin).

Answer (score 2):

The bash completion for rpm is provided directly by the bash-completion project, not by rpm itself. It is clearly a bug. Feel free to file an issue here: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion